# No input files specified - symfony app set up with homestead

Tags: php, symfony, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I tried to use homestead to iset up Symfony using instruction here. Everything seemed to run correctly in git bash, but after `php bin/console server:start`, I get "No input files specified" when I go to localhost:8000 or http://127.0.0.1:8000 or symfony-demo.test. I have searched around and tried different approaches for the past 6 hours, but still can't get it work. I'm quite new to virtual machine and vagrant, and complete newbie to Symfony so any help would be highly appreciated! 
Here is my Homestead.yaml file:

```
folders:
    - map: C:\php-apps
      to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
    # - map: homestead.test
    #   to: /home/vagrant/code/homestead/public
    - map: symfony-demo.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/symfony_demo/web
      type: symfony
```

Here is the host file:

```
#192.168.10.10 homestead.test

192.168.10.10 symfony-demo.test
```

Here is latest commands I ran in git bash:

```
vagrant@homestead:~$ ls
code
vagrant@homestead:~$ cd code/
vagrant@homestead:~/code$ cd symfony_demo/
vagrant@homestead:~/code/symfony_demo$ ls
symfony  symfony-demo
vagrant@homestead:~/code/symfony_demo$ cd symfony-demo/
vagrant@homestead:~/code/symfony_demo/symfony-demo$ ls
app  bin  composer.json  composer.lock  phpunit.xml.dist  README.md  src  tests  var  vendor  web
vagrant@homestead:~/code/symfony_demo/symfony-demo$ php bin/console server:start


 [OK] Server listening on http://127.0.0.1:8000                                                                         


vagrant@homestead:~/code/symfony_demo/symfony-demo$
```

I tested Laravel before and it worked fine, though http://127.0.0.1:8000 was also showing laravel after started the symfony server in `symfony-demo`, so I commented out Laravel site in `host` file and `Homestead.yaml` and ran vagrant --provision. Afterwards when I went back to `symfony-demo` directory and launched the server again, everything starts to show "No input files specified".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out so I want to post my solution here just in case someone else ran into the same issues as me. So I'm on a windows 10, before my own config files, please do read careful through these 3 resources:
[Using homestead to install Symfony on various version documentation by Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/setup/homestead.html)
[Installing Symfony 3 with vagrant and homestead by Sanket Patel](https://medium.com/@s4nk3tp/how-to-install-symfony-3-using-vagrant-homestead-6f6a227a95f)
[Set up homestead on windows by JBorbón](http://backendtime.com/setup-laravel-homestead-windows/)

Here is what I did:

1. Create a homestead folder on my C drive.
2. Install symfony installer on C drive and move it into the homestead
   folder above.
3. Create my project inside of homestead folder above (my project is
   called autotrader).
4. Download vagrant, virtual box and set up homestead according to
   [their documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/homestead). I set up a directory called
   homesteadserver where I cloned homestead in.
5. Configure my Homestead.yaml file as below:

   ```
           folders:
               # - map: ~/code
               #   to: /home/vagrant/code
               - map: C:\homestead
                 to: /home/vagrant/homestead

           sites:
               # - map: homestead.test
               #   to: /home/vagrant/code/public
               - map: autotrader.test
                 to: /home/vagrant/homestead/autotrader/web
                 type: symfony
   ```
6. Configure my host file as below:

   ```
   192.168.10.10 autotrader.test
   ```
7. Go to my homestead server and vagrant up and provision.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may originate from your `php.ini` file due to an incorrect value set for the `open_basedir` variable.
stop local server, comment line then restart server.